# Django password reset/change view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-authentication

I want to implement **password reset/change** feature in my app i just googled it & saw everyone using Django default [Authentication Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). Is this the best way to do this?

I'm new to django so i don't know much about this so suggest me the best way to do this.

***currently i implemented this***

```
path('password_change/done/', auth_view.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(
                                                template_name='registration/password_change_done.html'),
                                                name='password_change_done'),

    path('password_change/', auth_view.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
                                                template_name='registration/password_change.html'),
                                                name='password_change'),

    path('password_reset/done', auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
                                                template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),
                                                name='password_reset_done'),

    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
                                                template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'),
                                                name='password_reset_confirm'),


    path('password_reset/', auth_view.PasswordResetView.as_view(
                                                template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html'),
                                                name='password_reset'),

    path('reset/done/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
                                                template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'),
                                                name='password_reset_complete')
```

Comment: Yeah... Go ahead with Django's built-in auth views. If you feel you want some more modifications, inherit the corresponding classes and make changes accordingly.

Comment: It seems good to me too. That's the way I have done it before (and subclassing when needed)

Comment: Thanks i am gonna use default one. i will look for subclassing when needed.